# Why the Xcode automatic execute breakpoint when the App launch

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I set a function ( All Exceptions ) in Xcode ,

I have not set any breakpoint ,

but when start my App that the Xcode automatic to execute breakpoint for the main function .

I cannot understand it and i cannot solve it .

please help me to answer the question .

thanks very much .

it's the image , thanks to read :
[image: Click on me, you can see the picture description of the problem]

Comment: You have bug in your code.

Comment: Oh  ? what is it ? please you help

Comment: Happened to me also (Xcode 9 beta 5).
Noticed that the stack trace points to UIStatus bar. Removed the`UIStatusBarHidden` from the `.plist` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you set All Exceptions breakpoint, the app breaks not only on severe errors, but on possible errors as well.**

*If you want to debug in a particular place, then enable the breakpoint only for that particular window or view.* Don't keep it enabled for entire lifecycle of the app.

There are many flags that you can enable & disable to have a reflection in your Xcode. You should try to remove all the warnings, and if you are using Coredata be sure you are working with correct thread and MOCs (this being one the least bothered error).

Comment: thanks , remove the flag ( the flag is All Exceptions ) , the Xcode doesn't automatic breakpoint .  but i want to know why ? Could you please explain？

Comment: @user5465320: The compiler finds some errors in your code, they can be smaller as well. If you create an empty project with All Breakpoint and run with enabling it won't break. Since nothing much is there and all are perfect.

Comment: check the stacktrace and you will now which was the last class and method called.